# Animation loop and scaling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Well I've got a few question to ask! Firstly What this code is doing is creating and drawing snowflakes with unique density which will all fall at a different rate. My first question is how do i make this loop continuous?

Secondly, I've translated my origin point(0,0) to the middle of the canvas (it was part of the criteria). I've now got this issue in which that when the snowfall is called it will either be drawn on the left side of the screen or the right, not both. How do i solve this?

Finally i know when doing animations that you have to clear the canvas after each re-drawing, however i haven't added this in and yet it still works fine?

```
//Check to see if the browser supports
//the addEventListener function
if(window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener
    (
        'load', //this is the load event
        onLoad, //this is the evemnt handler we going to write
        false //useCapture boolen value
    );
}

//the window load event handler
function onLoad(Xi, Yy) {
    var canvas, context,treeObj, H, W, mp;  
    Xi = 0;
    Yy = 0;
    mp = 100;

    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    W = window.innerWidth;
    H = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;
    context.translate(W/2, H/2);

    var particles = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {

        particles.push({
        x: Math.random()*-W, //x
        y: Math.random()*-H, //y
        r: Math.random()*6+2, //radius
        d: Math.random()* mp // density
        })
    }


    treeObj = new Array();
    var tree = new TTree(Xi, Yy);
    treeObj.push(tree);



    function drawCenterPot(){
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = "1";
        context.strokeStyle = "Red";
        context.moveTo(0,0);
        context.lineTo(0,-H);
        context.lineTo(0, H);
        context.lineTo(-W, 0);
        context.lineTo(W,0);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }

    function drawMountain() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "#FFFAF0";
        context.lineWidth = "10";
        context.strokeStyle = "Black";
        context.moveTo(H,W);
        context.bezierCurveTo(-H*10,W,H,W,H,W);
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }

    function drawSky() {
        var linearGrad = context.createLinearGradient(-100,-300, W/2,H);
        linearGrad.addColorStop(0, "#000000");
        linearGrad.addColorStop(1, "#004CB3");
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = linearGrad;
        context.fillRect(-W/2, -H/2, W, H);
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();


        drawMountain();
        drawCenterPot();

    }




    function drawSnow(){
    context.fillStyle = "White";
        context.beginPath();
        for(i = 0; i<mp; i++) 
        {
            var p = particles[i];
            context.moveTo(p.x,p.y);
            context.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, Math.PI*2, false);
        }
        context.fill();
    } 


    function update() {
        var angle = 0;
        angle+=0.1;
        for(var i=0; i<mp; i++) {
            var p = particles[i];
            p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;
            p.y += Math.cos(angle+p.d) + 1 * p.r;
        }

        drawSky();
        drawSnow();
        draw();
    }

    function draw() {
        for(var i =0; i < treeObj.length; i++)
        {
        context.save();
        context.translate(Xi-H,Yy-W);
        context.scale(1, 1);
        treeObj[0].draw(context);
        context.restore();
        } 
    } 

        setInterval(update, 33);




}
```

Comment: This will be easier to debug if there's a working example - i.e. give us a jsfiddle.net link we can explore.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhansell/H79vp/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L5qUZ/1/ fixed few issues

Comment: omg thannk you SOO much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About your animation:**

What's happening is your flakes are falling out of view below the bottom of the canvas.

So when any flake's p.y+p.r > canvas.height you could:

- destroy that flake and (optionally) add another falling from above the canvas

or

- "recycle" that flake by changing its p.y to above the canvas.

**About your design working without context.clearRect:**

In your design, when you fill the whole canvas with "sky", you are effectively clearing the canvas.

**About your flakes only falling on half the screen:**

Instead of translating to mid-screen:

- Don't translate at all and let p.x be any Math.random()*canvas.width